# Yii1 web application change the language by itself

Tags: php, yii1.x

I'm working on yii1 web application, i will mention  my problem  in  simple way: 
i have home  view page,  i have created url  as the following :

```
 <a href="<?php echo  yii::app()->createUrl('home/Test') ; ?>">link</a>
```

in my Home controller i have  this simple  code :

```
 public  function actionTest(){
        var_dump(Yii::app()->language) ;
         exit() ;
 }
```

my project  supports two languages  Arabic  and English, 
when user change language  between Arabic and English , every  thing is working fine, layout , language and every thing except the  previous code.
after user  change  the  language if he click  on  previous link the  result will be EN whatever  the language  of app, if Arabic  or English, after var dumping the  language. and please note that every  link in the app was  created in the same way and it's  working fine except  this link  . why ?

any one  can advise  me  please  ?

Answer (score 0):

For problem described above, the problem was in routing. Application in some links doesn't route to the correct controller action.
The reason for that was in my project itself . because I have received the project after handing over of another  developer so I wasn't know all functions and rules that he used. So the problem was all actions that were not have spcifce role to render on home page,that was making the application routed to default action so it was returned to the default status of course as .httaccess said and give 302 status code as a response .
Thank you stack overflow